# Dymos how to use previous trajectory solution as initial guess?

Tags: openmdao

I am running my trajectory problem multiple times in a row while varying a parameter to generate plots and compare to other things. I think I can make it run faster by just using the previous solution as a guess.
Would I do something like

```
p['traj.phase_1.states:v'] = prev_p.get_val['traj.phase_1.states:v']
```

also is there a single function to load the file "dymos_simulation.db" into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dymos.run_problem` is intended to be the mechanism that makes this simple.

There is currently a PR that addresses some shortcomings, but expect it to be merged sometime today and included in dymos 0.18.0 in the next day or two.  In the meantime you can test against the source branch of the PR if you like:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/pull/510

First, you can simulate out the initial guess of the controls (this is not recommended if you're likely to hit a singularity in the ODE during your simulation).

```
dymos.run_problem(p, run_driver=False, simulate=True)
```

That will generate the file 'dymos_simulation.db'. Then you can run

```
dymos.run_problem(p, run_driver=True, simulate=True, restart='dymos_simulation.db')
```

It will use the simulated guess as the initial guess for the solution.  This should adequately satisfy the collocation constraints and give the optimizer an easier path to the solution.

Comment: thank you again Rob! I'll try it out with version 0.18

Comment: FYI 0.18.0 is out today.  Give it a try and let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Hi Rob, just tried it. I just ran my problem twice in a row, running the driver both times, first with restart=None and then with restart='dymos_simulation.db'. Seems like it didn't make any difference to the number iteration IPOPT took to reach a solution, and no errors were thrown

Comment: OK, investigating further-- by looking at IPOPT output files for both cases, it is doing SOMETHING. In the former case, the IPOPT objective value changes with each iteration and converges to the final value. I can see that in the latter case, using the sim file as initial guess, the objective starts at the final value converged value of the previous case, wiggles around a bit, and converges to the same value as it started. It takes about the same number of iters. I was hoping it would cut down the iters to 1 or two since it already had the solution. Seems I am missing something.

Comment: There are a few reasons why this could happen.  Sometimes starting exactly at the optimum leads to the optimizer seeming "confused" because it can't see good convexity in the approximated hessian.  Can you reach out to me via email and I can help you out further?